# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' while installing Sitecore Headless Rendering

Tags: jss, packages, jss-rendering-sdk

I have a `Sitecore 10.2` local instance. When I tried to install `Sitecore Headless Rendering 20.0.2` from [Sitecore Headless Rendering](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering.aspx), it gave an exception.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

**Stack Trace**

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +96
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +62
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.c.b__2_0(XmlNode x) +114
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +241
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +193
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +171
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServiceProviderBuilder.ConfigureServiceCollection() +142
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ConfigureServiceProvider() +225
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.get_ServiceProvider() +513
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.SitecorePerRequestScopeModule..ctor() +13

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +142
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +107
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1476
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +186
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +28
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +234
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1153
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +139
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +724
```

Please suggest how to fix this issue.

Comment: This issue would be better addressed on a forum like [Sitecore Slack](https://sitecore.chat)

Answer (score 1):

When instatlling `Sitecore Headless Rendering` package it included set of files like `config`, `Dlls`, `module items`, and `view`. There are DLLs that refer `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` assembly.

It looks like you might have missing the DLL file OR have a different version of the assembly configuration in `web.config`.

Here are a few suggestions to fix it:

1. Validate the web.config assembly reference.

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.14.0" newVersion="3.1.14.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

2. Ensure `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll` exist in `bin` folder with reference version.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: thx Sumit. I already tried this. Previously inside bin i had this dll with version 2.1.1.0 then i replaced it with desire version and changed bindingRedirect under web.config. but didn't fix this issue.